# Python pandas - merge groupby result to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I need to run a custom function on a df, and I want to be able to return a vector of values in exactly the same order as in the original data frame (e.g., merging back to the original df and then using just the new column).

At the moment my function is returning a simple list, which results in a Series with index column and another column which includes that list, see below

How can I combine that result back to the df??

Some other info:
 1. my function includes some business logic and needs access to all colls in the group, so I could not use transofrm
 2. I tried using series as a return type but then got typeerror seris.name has to be hashable (even if i set the name of the series before return)
 3. I want to avoid using DataFrame as a result of that function

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,1,2,1,2,2,1,3,1,2,3,2],"y":[random.random() for _ in range(12)]})

def myfun(rs,rownum=0):
    if rownum >= len(rs): return []
    return [rs.y] + myfun(rs,rownum+1)

q=df.groupby(df.x).apply(myfun)
```

Result:

```
x
1    [[0.199527553305, 0.652730337948], [0.19952755...
2    [[0.58150463154, 0.882898367661], [0.581504631...
3    [[0.793173748785, 0.29465803134], [0.793173748...
```

Update: the script below does what I want. The only way I found it to work is if I save the index value in the original recordset, and then update by that number:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,1,2,1,2,2,1,3,1,2,3,2],"y":[random.random() for _ in range(12)]})

def myfun(rs):
    def myfun_loop(rs,rownum=0,idx=[],val=[]):
        if rownum >= len(rs):
            return (idx,val)
        return myfun_loop(rs,rownum+1,idx+[rs.index[rownum]],val+[rownum])
    v=myfun_loop(rs)
    return pd.DataFrame({"idx":v[0],"val":v[1]})


g=df.groupby(df.x)
q=g.apply(lambda x:pd.DataFrame(myfun(x)))
q.set_index(["idx"],inplace=True)
df["val"]=None
df.update(q)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Currently your function returns a list of identical Series, not "a simple list". When applied to the GroupBy object this gives a Series of list of Series (check the outputs of `type(q)`, `type(q[1])`, `type(q[1][0])`). So you first need to fix the output of your function.

Comment: I updated the post with an working example, but the implementation is quite ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what yours does, just more concisely:

```
df["val"] = df.groupby(df.x).apply(
                lambda rs: pd.DataFrame(
                    {"idx": rs.index, 
                     "val": rs.reset_index().index})
            ).set_index(["idx"])
```

This way there is no need of defining a recursive function to implement this functionality.

Comment: Recursion is indeed irelevant here, I was copying code from a complex example where it is.

So If I understand correctly, when one assignes a df to a column in another, index is used underneath to join them? That was the important detail I was missing!